# If $A^TA$ is invertible, then $A$'s columns are linearly independent (not necessarily square matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My textbook wants me to verify that when  $A^TA$ is invertible, then $A$'s columns are linearly independent. However, I may not assume that $A$ is invertible, or even square. How should I go about?

Comment: Are these real matrices?

Comment: Yes, real matrices

Comment: you need not assume $A$ is invertible or even a square matrix as $A^TA$ would be anyways square matric so you can think of invertibility and determinant

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Please elaborate.

Comment: @GitGud : He said "we need not assume $A$ is invertible or even a square matrix".. I am just confirming that for a non square matrix also $A^TA$ is a square matrix so it is invertible.... Nothing to be taken so seriously though..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik What puzzles me is the determinant idea, I don't see how to work with it if $A$ isn't a square matrix.

Comment: @GitGud : I am talking  about invertibility of $A^TA$ and independene of $A$... that can be done right...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Let $A \in \Bbb R ^{n \times m}$ and suppose $A$'s columns are linearly dependent, then show there is $0 \neq x \in \Bbb R^m$ such that $Ax = 0$. What does this tell you about $(A^TA)x$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of columns in $A$.

$A^T$ has the same rank as $A$ (because column rank and row rank are the same). Since rank is essentially dimension of the image of a map represented by matrix, $\mathrm{rank}(AB) \leq \min(\mathrm{rank}(A), \mathrm{rank}(B))$. So, $\mathrm{rank}(A^T A) \leq \min(\mathrm{rank}(A^T), \mathrm{rank}(A))$.  But since $n$ is the number of columns in $A$, $A^T A$ is $n$ by $n$ matrix, and since it's invertible, its rank is equal to $n$. On the other hand, if columns in $A$ weren't linearly indepdendent, then $\mathrm{rank}(A) < n$, so $n = \mathrm{rank}(A^T A) \leq \min(\mathrm{rank}(A^T), \mathrm{rank}(A)) < n$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices such that $BA$ makes sense, and suppose $BA$ is invertible.  Thinking of $A$ and $B$ as linear transformations, $BA$ represents their composition; since $BA$ is invertible we have that $A$ is one-to-one (this is a general fact about compositions of functions), and a matrix defines a one-to-one transformation if and only if its columns are independent.